# Upgrading code from jQuery UI 1.7 to 1.8 failing

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I have some old jquery UI code that I want to upgrade to todays standards. Since my code was written for jQuery UI 1.7.3 I've decided to upgrade to code release by release. A release list is found here: https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/

So if I open 1.8 Upgrade Guide I can see what was changed. So far so good. As far as I can see, the following changes apply to my code:

- Renamed _init() to _create()
- Renamed _setData() to _setOption()
- Removed _getData() since it should never be overridden
- $.widget() now accepts a base widget to extend as the second parameter; defaults to $.Widget

Though I am not sure what to do with `_getData()`. Must I replace this with `_Option` or `_getOption`?. This is not clear in the guide.

Nevertheless, changing my code results in a nonworking application. I hope someone can help me out.

This is (partly) my old code:

```
_init: function () {
      var index = this.options.index;
      var num_ranks = this._RANKS.length;
      var suit = parseInt(index/num_ranks);
      this._setData('suit', suit);
      this._setData('rank', index - (suit * num_ranks));
      this.element.addClass('container')
               .append('<div class="downturned">');
    },
    _suit: function () { return this._getData('suit'); },
    _rank: function () { return this._getData('rank'); },
```

And further in the code:

```
   $.widget('ui.card', Card); //Create the widget
   $ui.card.getter = "is_downtunred";
```

The above I've changed (using the guide) to:

```
_create: function () {
      var index = this.options.index;
      var num_ranks = this._RANKS.length;
      var suit = parseInt(index/num_ranks);
      this._setOption('suit', suit);
      this._setOption('rank', index - (suit * num_ranks));
      this.element.addClass('container')
               .append('<div class="downturned">');
    },
    _suit: function () { return this._getOption('suit'); },
    _rank: function () { return this._getOption('rank'); },
```

And further in the code (did not change anything here):

```
   $.widget('ui.card', Card); //Create the widget
   $ui.card.getter = "is_downtunred";
```

But this brakes the application. Anyone knows why? What am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `this._getData()` with `this.option()` resolved my issue